# INSERT subquery in UPDATE Query

Tags: mysql

Can I run an `INSERT` subquery in UPDATE SET query? Example:

```
UPDATE sometable
      SET sometable.val = sometable.val + NOW()
     WHERE NOT isnull((INSERT INTO othertable values(sometable.val, 2, 3)));
```

Can I write something like `is not null` or anything just to insert value from `sometable` to `othertable`.

I can solve this with a function, but does anyone know a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No that is not possible, you need to post your insert first, then you can use last_insert_id() to get the key from the last inserted record as part of your update query.